# Unable to read the application.properties from the GIT repository using Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I;m trying to get the contents application.properties from my GIT repository using Spring Boot Cloud Config server, where I've saved the eureka server's URL.
Am using spring boot version 2.3.4 with cloud dependency version - Hoxton.SR5.

**application.properties in my config server:**

```
spring.application.name=config-server-git

spring.config.name=sb-employee-cloud-config-server-git

server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/Venkatesh-8203/sb-employee-cloud-config-server-git.git

#spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true

#spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true
```

**Config server startup:**

2021-04-26 20:48:44.711  INFO 14260 --- [           main] m.EmployeeCloudConfigServerSBApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2021-04-26 20:48:45.486  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=53849fa2-bc07-3ec6-b44c-0fe3da5e9e6a

2021-04-26 20:48:45.933  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)

2021-04-26 20:48:45.943  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2021-04-26 20:48:45.943  INFO 14260 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]

2021-04-26 20:48:46.072  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2021-04-26 20:48:46.072  INFO 14260 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1345 ms

2021-04-26 20:48:46.427  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

2021-04-26 20:48:49.936  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'

2021-04-26 20:48:49.986  INFO 14260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''

2021-04-26 20:48:50.199  INFO 14260 --- [           main] m.EmployeeCloudConfigServerSBApplication : Started EmployeeCloudConfigServerSBApplication in 6.533 seconds (JVM running for 6.87)

2021-04-26 20:48:59.226  INFO 14260 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2021-04-26 20:48:59.226  INFO 14260 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2021-04-26 20:48:59.234  INFO 14260 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms

When I hit the URL - http://localhost:8888/config-server-git/default

or

http://localhost:8888/sb-employee-cloud-config-server-git/default,
I get the "Whitelabel Error Page" screen.

**application.properties in my producer service:**

```
spring.application.name=employee-producer

server.port=8080

#eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8090/eureka

eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true

eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888

spring.cloud.config.name=sb-employee-cloud-config-server-git
```

Could you please suggest on how to overcome this.
I'm trying with test application, as I've the same issue in my official application.

Thanks,
Venkatesh

Answer (score 1):

The employee-producer properties should be accessible at http://localhost:8888/employee-producer/default
and the config server properties at http://localhost:8888/application/default

In your Git repository, make sure the names of the application properties correlate to the names given in the application.properties file. For your producer service, for example, spring.application.name=**employee-producer** so in your config repo, there should be a file called **employee-producer.properties**.